# Rails - Change data in #index depending on data in #view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and sometimes I get stuck. Your help is really appreciated...

This is my webapp : http://histoiredecinqmots.herokuapp.com/index (in french). It uses Rails 4 and bootstrap (althought poorly). I'll describe it briefly :

It is an index of "stories". Stories contains words.

When you click on a story (via a green bootstrap "success" div), you go in #show for this story.

The #show display the words of the story.

Now, the app is made so every word you add record your I.P adress. You can add 5 words in the last 15 words. After that, you can't add any more words (you have to wait for other people to add words).

I would like to change the class of the boostrap class of the div from "success" to "danger" **in the #index** so it turns red **when you have no more words left.**

I use this code in my controller to count how many words are left :

```
def updates_left_calculation #Calculate how many words users can input
   user_ip = request.remote_ip
   @last_updates_ip = Word.where(story_id: params[:id]).pluck(:ip).last(15)
   @updates_left = 5 - @last_updates_ip.count(user_ip)
end
```

This code is used in #show, but it doesn't work in #index, I guess because of 'story_id: params[:id]'

So I'm stuck, I don't know how to change my data in #index depending on a value that I normally use in #show...

For additional information : this is my view for displaying the stories in the index :

```
  <% @sorted_stories.each do |story| %>
    <br>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-1" >
          <a class="btn btn-success styled" href="/stories/<%=story.id%>">
            <div class="centre"><%= story.title %></div>
          </a>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

It works with this code in the controller :

```
  def index #Show the stories
         @stories = Story
         @story = Story.new
         @sorted_stories = @stories.order("id DESC").page(1).per(100) #Kaminari helpers for pagination
  end
```

Thank you very much for any suggestion for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `#updates_left_calculation` method to the `Story` model, making the `user_ip` a parameter. Then, in your index, use that result to set the CSS you want.

```
class Story
  has_many :words, dependent: :destroy

  def last_update_ips
    @last_update_ips ||= words.order(desc: :id).limit(15).pluck(:ip).reverse
  end

  def updates_left_for(user_ip)
    5 - last_update_ips.count(user_ip)
  end
end
```

Then, you can use either/both of these methods in your controller and/or views.

```
class StoriesController
  def index
    @user_ip = request.remote_ip
    @stories = Story
    @story = Story.new
    @sorted_stories = @stories.order("id DESC").page(1).per(100)
  end

  def show
    @user_ip = request.remote_ip
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    @last_update_ips = @story.last_update_ips
    @updates_left = @story.updates_left(@user_ip)
  end
end
```

For your index view, you might try something like:

```
<% @sorted_stories.each do |story| %>
  <br>
  <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-1" >
    <a class="btn btn-success styled <%= "danger" if story.updates_left_for(@user_ip) < 5 %>" 
      href="/stories/<%= story.id %>">
      <div class="centre"><%= story.title %></div>
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm learning a lot with your answer. A few errors but this excepted this solution is perfect !

Comment: Excellent! I made a couple tweaks to your original code to spur your thinking on the matter - glad I could help!